# Asp.Net UserControl - accessing a child control in the parent page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

If for example my **userControl** has a **CheckBox** called **IsGreatCoder** and the userControl is embedded in a main page (parent page).

I normally have gained **access to the IsGreatCoder.Checked** value in the main-page by exposing it through a **public property** that I have to manually write (say "IsAGreatCoder").

If UserControl is included in the main page as "*userControl1*", then I would access it as **"userControl1.IsAGreatCoder".**

But, I was wondering if there was anyway to declare the UserControl such that all the UI controls added to it were declared as being public, that way allowing me to gain access to the actual controls in the main page (the parent).

Essentially I would like to be able do something like
**userControl1.IsGreatCoder.Checked**
instead of having to implement a property.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to have access to many more of the check-box's properties and it would be a pain to implement each one as a public property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, this isn't possible (setting an object's private designations as public automatically).

To make it a little easier, you could go in your designer view (if using Web Application Project) and edit each control declaration there to be public, but this will be overwritten whenever you make a UI change (it's auto-generated after all) so it's probably better to just:

```
public bool IsAGreatCoder
{
    get { return IsGreatCoder.Checked; }
}
```

Note that you'll need to differentiate your property naming from your control name.